# get string array from text list c++

Tags: c++, arrays, text-files

my text file was like

```
123456123456
Jason
uk
012456788
1000
456789456789
david
uk
012456788
1000
```

i'm trying to get the data from a text file and save it into arrays
however when i want to store the data from the text file into array it loop non-stop.
what should i do ? 
the problem exiting in looping or the method i get the data from text file ?

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct {
    char acc_no[12];
    char name[30];
    char address[50];
    char phone_no[12];
    double balance;

} ACCOUNT;

//function prototype
void menu();
void read_data(ACCOUNT record[]);

int main() {
    ACCOUNT record[31]; //Define array 'record'  which have maximum size of 30
    read_data(record);  
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------

void read_data(ACCOUNT record[]) {
    ifstream openfile("list.txt");              //open text file 

    if (!openfile) {
        cout << "Error opening input file\n";
        return 0;
    } else {
        int loop = -1;                  //size of array 
        cout << "--------------Data From File--------------"<<endl;
        while (!openfile.eof())  {
        if (openfile.peek() == '\n') 
            openfile.ignore(256, '\n');
        openfile.getline(record[++loop].acc_no, 12);
        openfile.getline(record[loop].name, 30);
        openfile.getline(record[loop].address, 50);
        openfile.getline(record[loop].phone_no, 12);
        openfile >> record[loop].balance;
        }
        openfile.close();               //close text file

        for (int i = 0; i <= loop + 1; i++) {
            cout << "Account "  << endl;
            cout << "Account No.  : " << record[i].acc_no << endl;
            cout << "Name         : " << record[i].name << endl;
            cout << "Address      : " << record[i].address << endl;
            cout << "Phone Number : " << record[i].phone_no << endl;
            cout << "Balance      : " << record[i].balance << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this code compile? You are returning a value from a function declared as `void`.

Comment: Add some cout print line so you'll know whether the looping is doing the job correctly.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice opss i i forget to change it just now btw the result still the same

Comment: @ydoow i did some test and it able to get the data but when the time i put it in loop the problem comes

Comment: Your test for openfile will always be true.  That's not the way to test whether open worked.

Comment: if (!openfile.[good](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/good/)())

Comment: @RyanHaining what does it mean ? how can i use if (!openfile.good())?

Comment: click the good link above.  it means there were no errors, it's not eof, it checks a bunch of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:

**The OP didn't properly cite the correct format in his data file. This answer is only valid up until the [last iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25354802/4).**

Don't use `.eof()` - that's more applicable to when you want to open the file and read it by characters.

A better way would be to use the insertion operator `>>` as follows:

```
#define ARR_SIZE 31

ACCOUNT temp;
ACCOUNT record[ARR_SIZE];
int i=0;

while(i < ARR_SIZE) {
  openfile >> temp.acc_no >> temp.name >> temp.address >> temp.phone_no >> temp.balance;
  record[i] = temp;
  i++;
}
```

Of course, even better is to use `std::string` to hold the values from the input file, in addition to using `std::vectors` instead of arrays.

Comment: why can't we just put 31 in 'record[]' in stead of define ARR_SIZE ??

Comment: @noobies: you can, but it defeats the purpose of making it easier to maintain. For example, if later on you decide to read more than 31, you have to change all references to that number in the program. The way as I suggest, means that you'll only have to do so once.

Comment: @noobies: I should also note that your array size for the `account_number` is wrong. It should be `12+1` or `13` as in C++, the extra character is used to store the `\0` character.

Comment: but when i use your code it cannot save the array string  which contain space properly

Comment: @noobies: I'm sorry, but I'm not following you - what array string? Which line in your example? Before I posted this code, I modified yours, and it reads and outputs the information perfectly.

Comment: opss, sorry my bad. my sample text file wasn't correct, it the name and address should be like 'Jason Derulo' and 'xxx,street 123,uk'

Comment: @noobies: With your new input, my answer is invalid. Good luck!

Comment: +1: For proposing an answer that OP should have accepted. Pfft.